# Разногласие в данных использования диска между сервером EC2 и консолью AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2

У меня возникла проблема с отображением данных использования диска в AWS консоли. Я присоединился к сервису примерно месяц назад и активно использую бесплатный уровень сервиса EC2 с установленной Ubuntu. Весь этот период я внимательно следил за метриками и статистикой использования ресурсов.

Однако, недавно я обнаружил расхождение в отображаемых данных. Когда я выполняю команду df -Th на своем EC2 сервере, она показывает, что использовано всего 5.1 гигабайта дискового пространства. В то время как в AWS консоли, данные о использовании диска практически в три раза превышают этот показатель, составляя 12 гигабайт.

На моем сервере установлены только Python версий 3.10 и 3.11, а также локальная база данных MongoDB Server Community. Я уверен, что не использовал 12 гигабайт дискового пространства.

Хотел бы узнать, сталкивался ли кто-то еще с подобной проблемой, и если да, как ее можно решить? К сожалению, я не могу обратиться в техническую поддержку AWS, так как они доступны только для платных клиентов.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и рекомендации по данной ситуации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, 12 Gb-Mo - это не мгновенное значение, а накопленное. Например, 1 Gb-mo - это хранение одного гигабайта в течение месяца, или 2х гигабайт полмесяца, или 30 гигабайт один день. Во-вторых, с чего ты взял, что тебе будут EBS считать по потраченному? EBS считают по выделенному. Выделили тебе 30 гб, Я так понимаю, скриншот ты делал на 12й день использования, поэтому и получилось 12 гб-мо